# How would I activate voice recognition for my iPhone app from the lock screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, voice

Is it possible to have my voice recognition app running in the background and whilst the phone is locked it can activate a feature. For example - The phone is locked but I say the word "yell" and the phone plays a sound OR executes a command. What options do I have here?

Thanks

Comment: Would anyone be able to answer this question?

Comment: did you found any solution for it ???